# Azure api app action being called multiple times

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created a logical app which has 1 trigger and 2 actions.
1 action fetches data from database and passes data to the second.
When there are lot of records fetched from database the second app takes time to insert data and the action is being called multiple times.
Is there some timeout which needs to be set somewhere.

Comment: Check the output in the portal, it should log all actions, and you can see the data being sent and retrieved from each step

Answer (score 0):

give out more details such as your codes so that I can understand your 'trigger' and 'action'. I think it's better to fetch all records out from 1st db and pass them to 2nd db at one time. If that, maybe your 'action' will be triggered only once.